# Grails GORM nested has-many relationship query

Tags: hibernate, grails, nested, grails-orm, has-many

I try to get all posts that are adressed to an audience containing one specific user by:

```
StreamPost.findAllByAudience(Friendzone.findAllByFriends(User.findAllById(2)))
```

or

```
def posts = StreamPost.where {
    audience.friends.id ==~ userId
}.list()
```

First results in

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - No value specified for parameter 1
```

Second does not work either, returns:

```
[]
```

I have the following domain model:

```
class StreamPost {
    static belongsTo = User
    Friendzone audience

    Date postTimestamp
    String postComment
    String postType

    static constraints = {
        postType inList: ['event','activitylevel','checkin','rating']
    }
}

class Friendzone {
    static belongsTo = User
    static hasMany = [friends:User,
                      streamposts:StreamPost]
    User owner

    String zoneName
    static constraints = {
        owner nullable: false
        friends nullable: false
    }
}

class User {
    static hasMany = [friends:User,
                      friendzones:Friendzone,
                      streamposts:StreamPost]
    static mappedBy  = [ friends: 'friends' ]

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username nullable: false
        password nullable: true
    }
}
```

So user1 might do a post visible for his friendzone1 which contains user2 and user3.
Now I want to get all posts which are visible for user2...

Which ist the best method doing this? dynamic finders, where queries, criteria or hql? How can I avoid previous mentioned errors?

Database scheme:

```
table: user
id  |  username
1   |  user1
2   |  user2

table: user_friendzone
user_id  |  friendzone_id
2        |  1

table: friendzone
id  |  owner_id  |  zone_name
1   |  1         |  user2only

table: stream_post
id  |  audience_id  |  post_comment
1   |  1            |  comment
```

**Edit 19.08.2015**

I think the friendzone class causes the problems. With Emmanuel's comment I figured out that the error (same error as above) is thrown trying to query a friendzone. For example:

```
def audience = Friendzone.get(1)
```

Maybe it is the relationship to the "user class"

```
static belongsTo = User
static hasMany = [friends:User,
                  streamposts:StreamPost]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def user = User.get(2)
def audiences = Friendzone.findAllByFriends(user)
def posts = StreamPost.findAllByAudienceInList(audiences)
```

I wrote it this way to make it easier to read, and to find which query is failing.

Comment: Great idea! Query fails at:
`def audiences = Friendzone.findAllByFriends(user)`
updated question with database scheme

Comment: `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - No value specified for parameter 1`

Answer (score 1):

Got it done by changing StreamPost class:

```
class StreamPost {
    static belongsTo = [owner:User, audience:Friendzone]

    User owner
    Friendzone audience

    Date postTimestamp
    String postComment
    String postType

    static constraints = {
        postType inList: ['event','activitylevel','checkin','rating']
    }
}
```

with following query:

```
def user = User.get(userID)
def posts = StreamPost.findAllByAudienceInList(user.friendzones.asList())
```

Comment: Awesome! That was quite the puzzler. I tried a where() query, but I just could't quite get it. I'm glad you found an elegant solution.